# Position fixed height and width is cutting of child elements

Tags: html, css, fixed

I'm working on a online-shop for a winery. Link to the page is http://develope.haimerl.at/shop. In the shop page all wines are shown with some information. Every second product div should be a bit smaller which works fine in screen widths `under 1000px` but doesn't work from `1000px or higher`.
I'm working with a bought wordpress theme and was looking for any breakpoints in `CSS` that would explain this behaviour. When I'm setting a `fixed height` with the `:nth-child` operator it just cuts of the child elements.
Maybe, has anyone got an idea how could I manage that every second element is a bit smaller than the other ones?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you show me a code snippet from the problematic part?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply Ajaj in the comments helped me out already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your css code there one breakpoint which is affecting your **pile-item-even-spacing** class which has min-width: 999px.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 999px)
.pile-item-medium-3d:not(.pile-item-small-3d):not(.pile-item-large-3d) .pile-item-even-spacing, .pile-item-medium-3d:not(.pile-item-small-3d):not(.pile-item-large-3d) .pile-item-portrait-spacing {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Please comment/remove and it'll work.

Comment: It worked thank you so much! I was getting crazy with that already...just didn't see that one